# How to make the buttons be centered and have some margin in between them with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have 4 buttons that I want to be centered and have like the same amount of margin in between them so it's gonna look something like this:

|--button--button--button--button--|

What's the best way to do this? Because i am giving the margin my self now but sometimes it yeets one of the button's underneath other button's

```
<div id="">
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Print Label</button>
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Label Wijzigen</button>
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eanScan">Scan</button>
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Verzenden</button>
</div>
```

and this is my css

````
#buttons {
    margin: 22px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    height: 175px;
    width: 175px;
    text-align: center;
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container my-3 bg-light">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center d-flex justify-content-between">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways,

one way is to target all buttons but not the last one

```
button:not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
```

another way is to target the button if after another button

```
 button + button {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the class `d-flex` an `justify-content-around` You can have evenly big space around your buttons in the parent div:

```
<div id="" class="d-flex justify-content-around">
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Print Label</button>
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Label Wijzigen</button>
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eanScan">Scan</button>
   <button id="buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Verzenden</button>
</div>
```

For more flexbox items **[LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)**